# Display multiple values from listView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to search in an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database and display the result in a ListView, but I can't get the result that I want. It returns something like {1222233333,0909098886} which is not what I'm looking for. The result should be something like this, below each other on a listView:

```
1222233333

0909098886
```

The following code is in DBAdapter.

```
public ArrayList<String> getMeterNUmber1(String Date) throws SQLException
{
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{Date};

    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ?",whereArgs);

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(mCursor.getString(0));
    }

    return results;
}
```

In this class I'm using sharedPreferences to store the result and pass it to the next class like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("Shareusername",dbUser.getMeterNUmber1(ss).toStrin());
editor.commit();
```

This is how I'm trying to display the result in a ListView:

```
String sharedUsername;
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedUsername = settings .getString("Shareusername","null");

String [] value =  new String[] {sharedUsername};

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<PojoClass>();
customerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,value);
listView.setAdapter(customerListAdapter);
```

If there is something I'm doing wrong, please help me.

Log

```
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{scann.barcode.scan/scann.barcode.scan.Result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at scann.barcode.scan.DBAdapter.getMeterNUmber1(DBAdapter.java:272)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at scann.barcode.scan.Result.onCreate(Result.java:58)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-18 21:17:44.405: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing them in shared preferences? You currently are saving your entire String array as a String when saving it which is why it shows as only one item in your adapter

Comment: so what must i do because im stuck,i dont know what to do?

Comment: No no no no no. SharedPreferences is never the way to go to pass data to "the next class". SharedPreferences is meant to store user settings that will be saved between application instances. Look into `Intent`s and plain Jane setters/getters if the classes are not Activities.

Comment: @djItu : see my edit answer to date instead for ArrayList in SharedPreferences and only query db when u want to show data in ListView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to split the string retrieved from `SharedPreferences` to a String array to show in ListView as:

```
String[] value=sharedUsername.split(",");

// Your code here...
```

There is no need to store `ArrayList` in `SharedPreferences`, just store the date in SharedPreferences as:

```
SharedPreferences settings =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
        getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("datestr",ss);
editor.commit();
```

And now retrieve data from the database using date when you want to show it in ListView as:

```
String sharedUsername;
SharedPreferences settings =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
shareddate = settings .getString("datestr","null");

ArrayList<String> sharedUsernamearr=null;
if(shareddate !=null){
   sharedUsernamearr=dbUser.getMeterNUmber1(shareddate);
}
else{
  // Do your code here
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<PojoClass>();
if(sharedUsernamearr !=null){
    customerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                  sharedUsernamearr);
    listView.setAdapter(customerListAdapter);
}
else{
    // Add your code here....
}
```

Comment: thanx it works but the problem it returns result inside this []so how can i remove it []? example: [1234567890123]

Comment: @djItu : you can use String.replace() for removing [ and ] and see my edit answer to avoid all this  unnecessary code

Comment: i have tried but it gives me error on this line,for this name sharedUsernamearr. customerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                           sharedUsernamearr);

Comment: it crashes when is supposed to display

Comment: @djItu : make sure you are getting data from db in  sharedUsernamearr ArrayList and post log also when crashing

Comment: @djItu : you are getting error because you are passing null to getMeterNUmber1 or maybe dbUser not initialize so i think you can solve your issue using String.replace

Comment: when i checked shareddate with Log if it has data, i found it but when i checked it after this Line sharedUsernamearr = db.getMeterNUmber1(shareddate); i get Null

Comment: @djItu : what data have in shareddate?

Comment: this data {1/1/1} wich is from database